# Automation of DOH Robot tests interrumped by Pop-up message

Tags: dojo, selenium-rc, doh, doh-robot

In order to automate DOH tests during our build process, I use Selenium RC to launch different browsers (IE and Firefox) on a server placed on a different domain than the build machine. Each browser is directed to our runTests.html in order to start DOH.

Sometimes, when a test that uses doh.robot starts, the following message is shown:

*"DOH has detected that the current web page is attempting to access DOH, but belongs to a different domain than the one you agreed to let DOH automate. If you did not intend to start a new DOH test by visiting this Web page, press Cancel now and leave the Web page"*

but since these tests are unattended it just sits there waiting for someone to click OK, and Selenium times out (in IE 8 it seems like the pop-up disappears automatically but the robot does nothing afterward).

As I said, it doesn't always happen. After you click OK on the Pop-up, the message will stop showing, and the message can go away for several sessions, but then it will show again in which seems to be an arbitrary way.

Does anyone knows a way to prevent this pop-up from showing?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the correct way to do it, but in util/doh/robot/DOHRobot.java, you may be able to modify the code to not check that or always simulate pressing "OK". I haven't tried it myself, but I may also need to do that for some of our automated testing.

Answer (score 0):

When the DOH robot is initialized, it first tries to click in the upper left corner of the page you are trying to test. If you obscure this div (you can see it with firebug), then the message will pop up. I think the problem is that your page isn't always loading up quick enough.

It is somewhat of a challenge to fix this. I haven't used DOH in awhile, but I don't think there is any way you can use a setTimeout to fix this. (You can try using setTimeout on the doh.run command, but it might be the case that the DOH robot clicks that div before parsing any doh commands.)

Another thing you might be able to do is add a sort of "wait" command to Selenium, or whatever shell command you are using to fire up the system.